# My Video Tag Is Not Working I have the Video and Written Right Path

Tags: html, reactjs, video

My Video Is Not Playing Plz Help

The Code

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHzBZ.png)

Website Image

[See The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWMtf.png)

Comment: Don't post code as images, please.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
// import video file
import vdo from './Video.mp4';

// jsx
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src={vdo} type="video/mp4">
    // if browser does not support video tag it displays below message
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```